# Interface as a return type gives problems

Tags: c#, interface

I have an error in the following implementation. It says that OnlineWebStore_Process cannot implement the interface IWebStore because they don't have a matching return type. But the method returns Item which implements the IItem interface used as return type in the IWebStore interface. What's a good solution to this problem?

```
public interface IItem
{
    string id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}

public interface IWebStore
{
    List<IItem> GetOnlineItems();
}

public class Item : IItem
{
    public Item(string _id)
    {
        id = _id;
    }

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineWebStore_Process : IWebStore
{
    public List<Item> GetOnlineItems()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        return items
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't change it so it returns a List<IItem>?

Comment: Another thing - it's convention that all property names start with capital letter. Your properties should be Id and Name

Comment: I did change it now and it works. Thank you. Also, I will change the property names to capital letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class OnlineWebStore_Process : IWebStore
{
    public List<IItem> GetOnlineItems()
    {
        List<IItem> items = new List<IItem>();

        return items;
    }
}
```

Your method signature has to be exactly the same, you can't take a subclass instead. If you do return a subclass you're losing a part of your abstraction and the interface contract is broken.

Comment: Like the OP's code, you're missing a `;` at the end of the return statement.

Comment: item.Add(new Item(id)) to the list gives a problem. It says it cannot convert Item to IItem.

Comment: @KasperHansen: your `List<Item>` had to be `List<IItem>`. Look at the definition in `IWebstore`. @Abelenky: cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I must have overlooked something. It works now as you have described.

Answer (score 3):

GetOnlineItems() should return `List<IItem>`

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Item> GetOnlineItems()
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    return items
}
```

Here you return List instead of List. This way you don't have your IWebStore method implemented. Here is the correct way:

```
public List<IItem> GetOnlineItems()
{
    List<IItem> items = new List<IItem>();
    items.Add( new Item( "1" ) ); // Adding an instance, which implements the interface IItem

    return items;
}
```

Comment: That Item constructor wants a string.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you method signatures need to be same. And secondly `List<Item>` is not child of `List<IItems>` like `Item` and `IItem`. They are totally different type.